# How to use 'ngModel' with form control name?

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular8

I have 2 textareas, if the user enters or inserts the value, need to update on other textarea field as well.

My be I can use the `change` function to do that, But I tried to use the ng-model with the control name. getting error. how to fix this? or can't we use the control name with ngmodel to gathered?

here is my textarea:

```
<textarea name="control-name" [(ngModel)]="control_name_text" formControlName="ControlName"  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" cols="85" rows="5" placeholder="Enter Control Name"></textarea>
```

another one:

```
<textarea name="pageUrl" [value]="control_name_text"  cols="85" rows="5" placeholder=""></textarea>
```

i have declared the `control_name_text` - in ts file as well. getting error as:

```
Can't bind to 'ngModelOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'textarea'.
```

any help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you importing `FormsModule` in your `app.module.ts`?

Comment: in .html, you can get the value of a reactive form control like `[value]="myForm.get('myControlName').value"` -if you has a formGroup "myForm" with a formControl "myControlName". NOT use [(ngModel)]

Comment: Please take a look at this: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms There is all you need to know. First off, don't use ngModel with reactive forms.

Answer (score 5):

There's no reason to use ngModel with reactive forms if thats what you are doing.

In this case you can just grab the value from the form control and use that for the input value

```
<form [formGroup]="exampleForm">
  <textarea formControlName="userText" cols="85" rows="5" ></textarea>
  <textArea [value]="userText"> </textArea> 
</form>
```

Its not required but in your component you can also shorten the formControl reference using a get property.

```
get userText() {return this.exampleForm.get('userText').value }
```

Example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sjn6du

Answer (score 2):

> Note: "[Using Reactive Froms with ngModel is deprecated in angular 6
>   and will be removed in angular 7](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel)"

so you have to remove `formControlName="ControlName"` from the first textarea.

```
<textarea name="control-name" [(ngModel)]="control_name_text"   [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" cols="85" rows="5" placeholder="Enter Control Name"></textarea>

<textarea name="pageUrl" [value]="control_name_text"  cols="85" rows="5" placeholder=""></textarea>
```

**Edit 2**

If you want to use reactive form use like this

```
<form [formGroup]="groupForm" >
  <textarea  formControlName="name" placeholder="Group Name" #textArea>
  </textarea>
</form>
<textarea name="" id="" cols="" rows="" [value]="textArea.value" [(ngModel)]="control_name_text"></textarea>
```

[working stackbliz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-spsg6o)

Comment: I am using reactive form, so required for validations. if I remove that, how can i validation with reactive form?

Comment: you can't use both reactive form and ngModel together because that feature is depreciated in angular6

Comment: In the second option, you should add `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"` to avoid *ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive* error. e.g. :  

`<textarea name="" id="" cols="" rows="" [value]="textArea.value" [(ngModel)]="control_name_text" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></textarea>`  

to avoid registering this form control we need to indicate that it's standalone in ngModelOptions.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML template you posted looks fine. To use two-way data binding for form inputs you need to import the FormsModule package in your Angular module.

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
         FormsModule      
    ]
```

Comment: But I have the form module already. unless adding this field all were worked well